# Why mybatis give up and return null?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

> ```
> @Select("Select distinct X from Table where X= #{param}")
> @Results({
>     @Result(column = "X", property = "a", many = @Many(select = "getIdsC")),
>     @Result(column = "X", property = "b", one = @One(select = "getTGN"))
> })
> TG getTG(@Param("param") int param);
> class TG{
>   String a;
>   List<Integer> b;
> }
> ```

I checked it, and for `getTGN` it returns proper string, as `"example"`.  However, for `getIdsC` it returns null - what seems be proper result, because there is no elements (maybe better result would be empty list).
My question is.
How force mybatis to return object of `TG tg` such that :
`tg.a=null, tg.a="example"`.  At this moment it returns `null`, although `a` field is not null.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse either declared type or mapping for a and b.
Can you see the inconsistency?

> property = "a", **many** ==> **String** a;
>
> property = "b", **one**  ==> **List** b;

This will work better this way:

> String <=> @One
>   List <=> @Many

This set appart, your code is good, the object is well populated, there is even an empty list instead of null when *getIdsC* does not return any result.